# How can I get the ending (x,y) coordinates of a view?

Tags: java, android, gesture, gesture-recognition, gestures

As far as I read, the method `getlocationonscreen()` gives the `(x,y)` coordinates of the top left of the view relative to the screen. How can I get the `(x,y)` of the bottom right of a view on the screen to know the coordinates of where it started and ended. Please refer to the image below.

[image]

Comment: Add `getWidth` to `x` and `getHeight` to `y`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the top left X,Y so to get the bottom right add the width and height.